# How to collect file and save on server with PHP

Tags: php, file

I know this similar question is asked before, but I can't find a solution to my specific problem.
I have this code, and it saves to a file and downloads it immediately to the desktop when run from the browser. But I need it to save it on a server. How do I do this with this specific code?

Do I need to save the file into a variable e.g. `$files` first?

```
<?php


header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=export_".date('n-j-Y').".xls "); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");

exit();

?>
```

Comment: check out [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file_put_contents)

Comment: @Dale I read it, but can't figure it out.. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some normal code:

```
<?php
echo "hey F4LLCON!";
?>
```

Executed, it behaves like we expect:

```
% php output.php 
hey F4LLCON!
```

Now I'll modify it to add output buffering and save to the file and write to stdout (using regular `echo` calls!):

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo "hey F4LLCON!";
$output_so_far = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();
file_put_contents("/tmp/catched.txt", $output_so_far);
echo $output_so_far;
?>
```

After executing, the output in the file `catched.txt` is equal to what we got earlier (and still get) on stdout:

```
hey F4LLCON!
```

Now I'll modify it again to show how generators from PHP 5.5 will provide you with an elegant solution that doesn't need to sacrifice performance (the previous solution requires you to save all the intermediate content in one giant output buffer):

```
<?php
$main = function() {
    yield "hey F4LLCON!";
};
$f = fopen("/tmp/catched2.txt", "wb");
foreach ($main() as $chunk) { fwrite($f, $chunk); echo $chunk; }
fclose($f);
?>
```

We aren't storing everything in one giant buffer, and we can still output to file *and* stdout simultaneously.

If you don't understand generators, here's a solution where we pass a callback "print" function to main(), and that function is used every time we want to output (only one time here).

```
<?php
$main = function($print_func) {
    $print_func("hey F4LLCON!");
};
$f = fopen("/tmp/catched3.txt", "wb");
$main(function($output) use ($f) {
    fwrite($f, $output);
    echo $output;
});
fclose($f);
?>
```

Comment: So I can place `$main = function() {` before and `}; $f = fopen("/tmp/catched2.txt", "wb");
foreach ($main() as $chunk) fwrite($f, $chunk);
fclose($f);
echo $output;` after my code? It gives me an syntax error. 

Can I use your method with my existing code?

Comment: You would only be able to do that if you used PHP 5.5 and didn't have `return` in the global scope (hopefully you don't). If you want a solution that almost certainly works with what you have got, use the first one (with `ob_start`). Read the PHP docs on output buffering: http://php.net/ob_start

Comment: Awesome it worked! It saves the file to my server, but one last thing, how can I specify the directory it saves the file? (with ob_start();)

Comment: Adjust the path passed to `file_put_contents`. Please try to understand the code, it's not complicated. All the functions are documented on http://php.net