# How to print to apache logs(access.log) from php script?

Tags: php, apache

I am working on a iOS app with php backend, I have a php service which is handling the file upload, I got the code from the internet but it is not working. I am trying to debug it by using print statement, but it is not printing anything to access.log, instead it is printing to the screen.
Could somebody tell me, how to print output to access.log from php script. Here is the php server-

```
 <?php
$firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
$lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
$userId = $_POST["userId"];


echo(var_dump($_POST));

$target_dir = "wp-content/uploads/2015/02";if(!file_exists($target_dir))
{
mkdir($target_dir, 0777, true);
}

$target_dir = $target_dir . "/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir))
{
echo json_encode([
"Message" => "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.",
"Status" => "OK",
"userId" => $_REQUEST["userId"]
]);

} else {

echo json_encode([
"Message" => "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.",
"Status" => "Error",
"userId" => $_REQUEST["userId"]
]);

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  The Apache access log is to record http/https requests made to the apache server.

Depending on what system you are running Apache on, the user "running" the apache server doesn't even have rights to the log file directory, much less the actual log files.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score -1):

Hope you are doing it for wordpress. You can do the following

file_put_contents(WP_CONTENT_DIR."/debug.log", print_r($_POST, 1), FILE_APPEND);

(Or) ref this one

https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/using-the-wordpress-debug-log

Then you can view the file stored in your file system /app/wp-content/debug.log

Comment: Check in your error.log file, the script errors are logged in to error.log file. So you will get to know is there any parse / syntax errors in your code. whereas access.log file contains the requests received by your apache web server. If you want to debug, write to a custom log file using the code you can debug:-  file_put_contents("/test.txt", print_r($_POST, 1), FILE_APPEND) ; This will write to the debug test file, which will help u in debugging when u send a request from IOS. All are written to this txt file.

Comment: Ensure create a empty file and provide permission 777 if u use linux hosted machine for php app. When u test a service consumed by mobile app, when the service provide JSON, its better to debug by writing to log file instead of printing in the screen.

Comment: How to do file uploading from iOS client app to the PHP service back end app Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549160/uploading-image-to-php-server